# How can I make an email template more accessible?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

I would have thought this would be much easier to find, like a From option on the New Email button, but it's an incredible amount of occulted navigation and clicks to start a new email based on a template:

New Items->More Items->Choose Form... [Select 'User Templates in File System], then select the template.

I would like to be able to easily add a big "New CV Mail' button next to the new mail button. Or the closest I can get to that.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen 2 other solutions.

1. Save the template in your Drafts folder, then "Forward" from there.
2. Save the template to your Desktop (or somewhere in the file system) and double click it.

Personally I set up some macros, like niton explains, and customized the ribbon. At the moment however, I am up against macro security, and SelfCert.exe not working properly to create a certificate to allow your own macros to run on your own PC. I believe the solution is to COPY (not move) the cert created by SelfCert.exe, using certmgr.msc, from the "Personal" folder, to the "Trusted Root Certificate" folder. Then you can add the certificate to the VB project using "Tools" > Digital Signatures (in the Visual Basic Editor). (and have "Macro Settings" in the "Trust Center" on "Notifications for digitally signed .......")

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Quick Steps` section in the Home tab. Hit `Create new`.

[image]

1. Choose a `Name` for your item.
2. `Choose action` > scroll down to `New Message`
3. `Show options`
4. Add your template ( subject, flags and of course your text).
5. `Choose a shortcut` will give you keyboard shortcut.
6. Hit `Finish` when you done fiddling with your template

The new item will appear in the `Quick Steps` group under Home button. Either click on it or use the assigned shortcut. Can't get faster than that.

Check this [article](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/customize-the-office-2010-ribbon-word-excel-outlook/) if you need instructions on how to customize your ribbon. After adding it you can rearrange the items just the way you want it.

Comment: 1. When I hit `New` (not `Create New`), I get a menu of options that includes `New email to:` and `Custom`. They seem the only suitable options. Neither offer the option to add an attachment to the email.

I don't want to create a new email template; I already have one under Forms, with an attachment. I want to add something to the UI to allow me to easily, without a million mouse clicks, to sent that template as an email instance to a chosen recipient.

Comment: I've added a picture above of the "event creator" in Quick Steps. Maybe that will clear things up.

Comment: No, because I've been hitting that Create New button all along. I still can't find a way to attach my CV to the Send Email action I create with it.

Comment: You can't attach it there. You can reference it.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code for this is described here http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/54-ms-outlook-2010-create-email-template-and-assign-a-quick-launch-button

"Full text in macro should look like this (obviously with path and file name amended):"

```
Sub MyTemplate()
Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates\MyTemplate.oft")
msg.Display
End Sub
```